# How to select top 10 records form all tables in a database and test for nulls in each field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run the code below to select the top 10 records from each table in my database.  From this subset, I want to find the percent age of nulls for each field in each table.  This code runs, but it gives me 10 records, not 10 from each table.  How can I modify this code to get the results I'm after?

```
DROP TABLE Columns

DECLARE @schemaName AS sysname;
DECLARE @tableName AS sysname;
DECLARE @columnName AS sysname;
DECLARE @schema_id AS int;
DECLARE @object_id AS int;
DECLARE @column_id AS int;
DECLARE @isNullable AS bit;
DECLARE @lastSchema_id AS int;
DECLARE @lastTable_id AS int;
DECLARE @recordCount AS bigint;
DECLARE @nullCnt AS bigint;
DECLARE @SQL as nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @paramDefinition NVARCHAR(max);

if exists(select name from tempdb..sysobjects where name LIKE'Columns%')
DROP TABLE Columns;

CREATE TABLE Columns (
    schema_id int,
    object_id int,
    column_id int,
    schemaName sysname,
    tableName sysname,
    columnName sysname,
    recordCnt bigint,
    nullCnt bigint,
    nullPct numeric(38,35) );

-- Set to the @lastSchema_id and @lastTable_id to NULL so that the first 
--  loop through the cursor the record count is generated.
SET @lastSchema_id = NULL;
SET @lastTable_id = NULL;

-- List of all the user schemas.tables.columns
--  in the database
DECLARE c_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT top (10)  schemas.schema_id
     , all_objects.object_id
     , all_columns.column_id
     , schemas.name AS schemaName
     , all_objects.name AS tableName
     , all_columns.name AS columnName
     , all_columns.is_nullable
 FROM sys.schemas
 INNER JOIN sys.all_objects
    ON schemas.schema_id = all_objects.schema_id
   AND all_objects.type = 'U'
 INNER JOIN sys.all_columns
    ON all_objects.object_id = all_columns.object_id
 ORDER BY schemas.schema_id
     , all_objects.object_id
     , all_columns.column_id;

OPEN c_Cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM c_Cursor
 INTO @schema_id
    , @object_id
    , @column_id
    , @schemaName
    , @tableName
    , @columnName
    , @isNullable;

-- Loop through the cursor
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    -- Get the record count for the table we are currently working on if this is
    --  the first time we are encountering the table.
    IF ( ( @schema_id <> @lastSchema_id ) OR ( @object_id <> @lastTable_id )
      OR ( @lastSchema_id IS NULL ) OR ( @lastTable_id IS NULL ) )
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = N'SELECT top (10) @recordCount = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ';';
        SET @paramDefinition = N'@recordCount bigint OUTPUT';

        exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                           @paramDefinition,
                           @recordCount = @recordCount OUTPUT;

    END

    -- If the column is NOT NULL, there is no reason to do a count
    --  Set the nullCnt and nullPct to 0
    IF ( @isNullable = 0 )
    BEGIN


        INSERT INTO Columns
             ( [schema_id]
             , [object_id]
             , column_id
             , schemaName
             , tableName
             , columnName
             , recordCnt
             , nullCnt
             , nullPct )
        VALUES
             ( @schema_id
             , @object_id
             , @column_id
             , @schemaName
             , @tableName
             , @columnName
             , @recordCount
             , 0
             , 0.0 );
    END
    -- If the column is NULL, count the number of NULL fields in the table.
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = N'SELECT top (10) @nullCnt = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + 
                   N' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + N' IS NULL;';
        SET @paramDefinition = N'@nullCnt bigint OUTPUT';

        PRINT @SQL;

        exec sp_executesql @SQL,
                           @paramDefinition,
                           @nullCnt = @nullCnt OUTPUT;

        INSERT INTO Columns
             ( [schema_id]
             , [object_id]
             , column_id
             , schemaName
             , tableName
             , columnName
             , recordCnt
             , nullCnt
             , nullPct )
        VALUES
             ( @schema_id
             , @object_id
             , @column_id
             , @schemaName
             , @tableName
             , @columnName
             , @recordCount
             , @nullCnt
             -- USE NULLIF in case there are no recods in the table
             , ISNULL( @nullCnt * 1.0 / NULLIF( @recordCount, 0) * 100.0, 0 ) );

    END

    -- Set the @lastSchema_id and @lastTable_id so that on 
    --  the next loop, if it's the same table there is no 
    --  need to recount the columns for the table.
    SET @lastSchema_id = @schema_id;
    SET @lastTable_id = @object_id;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c_Cursor
     INTO @schema_id
        , @object_id
        , @column_id
        , @schemaName
        , @tableName
        , @columnName
        , @isNullable;

END;

CLOSE c_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE c_Cursor;

SELECT *
  FROM Columns;
```

Comment: How do you reliably calculate the number of `NULL` rows in a table using 10 **random** rows from it?

Comment: I just want to grab a sample of data, just for a basic idea of percentage of nulls.  Yes, there could be no nulls at the top and a bunch below, or vice versa.  I'd like to iterate through all records in the DB, but it's just too, too, too big.  The query will never finish.  I'm fine just taking a small sample for this exercise.

Comment: You'd need a much bigger sample than 10 random rows (a table doesn't have a "too" or "bottom"). From what you're describing, it sounds like this is an XY problem. You might be better off asking about the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Well, 10 is just an arbitrary number.  It will be a million when I actually run it.  Again, I'm just trying to get it working and I can validate 10 records from each table much easier than validating a million records from each table.  Thanks.